# What are the positive values of $a$ for which the equation $a^x = x + 2$ has $2$ real solutions?

Tags: calculus

I have to find the positive values of $a$ for which the equation

$$a^x = x + 2$$

has $2$ **real** solutions. I am given the following $5$ options:

**A.** $(1, \infty)$

**B.** $(0, 1)$

**C.** $\bigg (\dfrac{1}{e}, e \bigg )$

**D.** $\bigg (\dfrac{1}{e^e}, e^e \bigg )$

**E.** $(e^{\frac{1}{e}}, \infty)$

I managed to cut one option out, but I don't know how to continue and find the right answer among the remaining $4$. This is what I did.

$$a^x = x + 2$$

$$a^x - x - 2= 0$$

Let

$$f(x)=a^x-x-2 \hspace{2cm} f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

So

$$f'(x) = a^x \ln a - 1$$

If we would have $a \in (0, 1]$, $f'(x)$ would always be negative (because of the $\ln a$ term), so the function would be a strinctly decreasing function, therefore it would be impossible for $f(x)= 0$ to have more than $1$ solution and since I need $f(x)=0$ to have $2$ solutions, this answer is invalid. So I can safely exclude the answer $B$.

I now know that the answer must be in the interval $(1, +\infty)$. The problem is that all the rest of the answers (**A**, **C**, **D**, **E**) are in this interval, and I don't know how to continue the problem and find the exact answer.

Comment: If $a>e$ then $a^{x}-x-2$ is increasing  so it cannot have two roots.

Comment: Looks like $A$ is the answer ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yw0zqmmr2z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(a)=f(b)=0$ for $a<b$, then there must exist $c\in(a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$ by Rolle's theorem. That is:

$$0=a^c\ln(a)-1$$

Solving for $c$ we get

$$c=-\frac{\ln(\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}$$

where we assume $a>0$ so that we may avoid negative bases (which has a solution $(a,x)=(-1,-3)$, but this matches none of the answers).

In order for $\ln(\ln(a))$ to be defined, we must have $\ln(a)>0$. In order for $\ln(a)>0$, we must have $a>1$.

Hence the answer is $a\in(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be A: $(1, \infty)$

For $a\in (1, \infty)$.

$a^0<0+2$ but $a^x$ is an exponential (growth) function and $x+2$ is linear so these two curves will intersect once in the positive numbers and once in the negative ones.

Looks something like this:

[image]

If $0<a<1$ you have an exponential decay function which will only have one solution: 
[image]